# ActiveMQ subscription timeout in C# application

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe, paho

I am using for the first time ActiveMQ to communicate a mobile and a cloud application. The idea is that the mobile device will send messages to some topics and the cloud application is subscribed to them.

My problem is that after some minutes (not a fixed value), even while the mobile app is sending data, the cloud application unsubscribes from the broker and I need to reset the cloud app in order to subscribe again and do not lose messages. For the cloud application I am using the M2MQTT Paho client. This is the code I am writing to connect and subscribe for the topics:

```
client = new MqttClient(MiddlewareAccountInfo.AWS_WSD_ENDPOINT, 
  MiddlewareAccountInfo.AWS_WSD_PORT, true, null, null, 
  MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);

  client.ProtocolVersion = MqttProtocolVersion.Version_3_1_1;
  client.shouldReconnect = true;
  client.Connect(MiddlewareAccountInfo.ACTIVEMQ_CLIENTID,
            MiddlewareAccountInfo.ACTIVEMQ_USERNAME, 
            MiddlewareAccountInfo.ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD, true, 60);

  ushort msgIdIOS = client.Subscribe(new string[] { "queue-iOS" },
             new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });

  ushort msgIdAndroid = client.Subscribe(new string[] { "queue-android" },
             new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });

  ushort msgIdClearDB = client.Subscribe(new string[] { "clear-database" },
             new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });

  client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttDataPublishReceived;
```

Can you suggest any configuration or way to implement the permanent subscription to the topics?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you change library?  I have previously used the [Apache NMS client](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/nms.html) although that was with the STOMP and OPENWIRE protocols not MQTT.  You could try that to see if it works better.

Comment: @PhilS I will try if changing the library solves the problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can configure reconnection in the NMS client connection string.  Details [here](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html).  I don't know if the Paho library has similar support